# How can I generate a weekly series which should have start date as month start date and end date should be start date + 6 in postgresql

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequence

Below is the query I have tried:

```
with weeks as (
select d::date start_date, case when to_char(d::date+6,'Month') = 
to_char(d::date,'Month') then d::date+ 6 else (date_trunc('month', 
to_timestamp(to_char(d::date,'YYYY-MM-DD') ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')) + interval '1 
month - 1 day')::date end as end_date
from generate_series('2022-01-01', '2022-07-30', '7d'::interval) d
)
```

I want results as:

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| '2022-01-01' | '2022-01-07 |
| '2022-01-08' | '2022-01-14 |

And it should go from 2022-01-29 to 2022-01-31 then for next month it should start from '2022-02-01' to '2022-02-07' and should continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would combine to `generate_series()` here. One for the start of the months, and one for the week starts.

Evaluating the week end can be achieved using the `least()` function by calculating the last day of the month:

```
select gw.week_start::date start_date, 
       least(gw.week_start::date + 6, date_trunc('month', gw.week_start) + interval '1 month - 1 day')::date as end_date
from generate_series('2022-01-01', '2022-07-30', interval '1 month') as gm(month_start)
  cross join generate_series(gm.month_start, gm.month_start + interval '1 month - 1 day', interval '1 week') as gw(week_start);
```

This returns:

```
start_date | end_date  
-----------+-----------
2022-01-01 | 2022-01-07
2022-01-08 | 2022-01-14
2022-01-15 | 2022-01-21
2022-01-22 | 2022-01-28
2022-01-29 | 2022-01-31
2022-02-01 | 2022-02-07
2022-02-08 | 2022-02-14
2022-02-15 | 2022-02-21
2022-02-22 | 2022-02-28
2022-03-01 | 2022-03-07
2022-03-08 | 2022-03-14
2022-03-15 | 2022-03-21
2022-03-22 | 2022-03-28
2022-03-29 | 2022-03-31
2022-04-01 | 2022-04-07
2022-04-08 | 2022-04-14
2022-04-15 | 2022-04-21
2022-04-22 | 2022-04-28
2022-04-29 | 2022-04-30
2022-05-01 | 2022-05-07
2022-05-08 | 2022-05-14
2022-05-15 | 2022-05-21
2022-05-22 | 2022-05-28
2022-05-29 | 2022-05-31
2022-06-01 | 2022-06-07
2022-06-08 | 2022-06-14
2022-06-15 | 2022-06-21
2022-06-22 | 2022-06-28
2022-06-29 | 2022-06-30
2022-07-01 | 2022-07-07
2022-07-08 | 2022-07-14
2022-07-15 | 2022-07-21
2022-07-22 | 2022-07-28
2022-07-29 | 2022-07-31
```